# How to filter columns that have values over 50 even in one cell in R?

Tags: r, filtering, multiple-columns

I have dataframe that has so many columns that i'm not able to specify column names one by one when filtering. So i need to filter all of the columns at once. And I want to leave the columns to dataframe that doesn't have any values over 50. I have transposed my dataframe but that doesn't help. I have also removed commas from my dataframe and that doesn't help either (i made numbers as integers and took that into consideration that i have to use 50000 insted of 50 in that case). Below is example codes that i have tried to use. I also post picture of my data frame in it's original form without transpose or removing?

In the first dataset samplw data is character data. When i change it how it is in the second example it is numeric and i want to filter values under 50000

```
#Removing values over 50kwh
daata <- apply(data8, 2, function(x) filter(x, x<50, preserve = TRUE))

daata <- apply(data, 2, function(x) filter_all(any_vars(x < 50)))

data6 <- data[sapply(data, function(x) max(x, na.rm = T) < 50)]

#example of data set
  xxx_877963267 xxx_9073498356 xxx_07839328
1       24.4560         5.8799       4.7854
2       12.5667         2.5643       0.7867
3       67.3453         7.4573       6.3298
4        0.3456         1.7398       2.3585
5        4.5675         2.3345       2.3556

xxx_7530298011 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), xxx_7530298028 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    xxx_7530695034 = c(1700, 1500, 1380, 1680, 1980, 1640), 
    xxx_7534110020 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), xxx_7530293026 = c(1400, 
    1450, 1450, 1500, 1610, 1760)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"

xxx_7530293026 = c(1400, 1450, 1450, 1500, 1610, 
    1760, 1950, 1970, 2100, 2130, 2230, 2260, 2280, 2150, 2180, 
    2050, 2150, 1840, 1740, 1660, 1610, 1920, 3710, 2280, 2390, 
    2360, 2210, 2340, 2390, 2210, 2310, 2360, 2340, 2180, 2340, 
    2310, 2340, 2100, 2340, 2360, 2260, 2150, 2360, 2340, 2440, 
    2130, 4270, 3010, 2980, 2940, 2970, 3060, 3030, 3060, 3100, 
    3150, 3050, 3100, 3160, 3010, 3110, 3070, 3150, 3150, 3190, 
    3310, 3220, 3250, 3330, 3410, 3300, 2120, 1400, 1440, 1530, 
    1790, 2900, 5740, 6680, 6720, 6850, 6330, 6740, 6650, 6480, 
    5410, 3340, 2950, 2790, 2510, 2160, 1830, 1610, 1510, 3120, 
    1850, 1880, 1960, 2120, 1940, 2050, 1990, 2180, 2140, 1990, 
    2050, 1700, 1900, 1770, 1830, 1680, 1610, 1830, 1720, 1850, 
    1660, 1610, 1180, 2510, 1180, 1180, 1220, 1220, 1270, 1350, 
    1480, 1640, 1660, 1770, 1790, 1880, 1900, 1920, 1810, 1830, 
    1720, 1810, 1550, 1460, 1400, 1350, 1350, 3400, 2310, 1770, 
    2250, 2250, 2010, 2290, 2180, 2200, 2530, 2140, 2200, 2400, 
    1900, 1550, 2090, 1940, 2050, 1770, 1790, 2120, 1900, 1990, 
    1990, 2270, 1900, 1700, 1420, 1660, 1720, 1750, 1440, 1850, 
    1570, 1750, 1570, 1880, 1420, 1660, 1550, 1460, 1330, 1640, 
    1400, 1640, 1440, 1570, 1610, 3120, 1920, 2010, 1990, 1850, 
    1960, 2010, 1850, 1940, 1990, 1960, 1830, 1960, 1940, 1960, 
    1770, 1960, 1990, 1900, 1810, 1990, 1960, 2050, 1790, 5910, 
    2150, 2370, 2160, 2330, 2190, 2360, 2320, 2310, 2470, 2390, 
    2400, 2480, 2510, 2400, 2440, 2510, 2450, 2500, 2480, 2460, 
    2320, 2310, 2200, 2200, 2100, 2260, 2060, 1970, 1980, 1950, 
    1870, 1920, 1880, 1880, 2040, 1860, 1830, 2330, 2780, 3100, 
    2900, 2650, 2790, 2690, 2450, 2380, 2260, 1950, 2010, 2020, 
    2090, 2080, 2140, 2240, 2300, 2320, 2280, 2440, 2440, 2450, 
    2270, 2420, 2330, 2340, 2520, 2520, 2660, 2280, 2410, 2180, 
    2390, 2470, 2610, 2600, 2630, 2750, 2800, 2770, 2850, 2890, 
    2900, 2500, 2810, 2790, 2790, 2580, 1890, 1840, 1780, 1800, 
    1660, 1760, 1740, 1740, 1760, 1820, 1790, 1810, 1820, 1740, 
    1850, 1740, 1770, 1720, 1560, 1740, 1820, 1930, 1590, 1710, 
    1890, 1930, 1950, 2070, 2120, 2200, 2310, 2290, 2300, 2350, 
    2450, 2460, 2480, 2470, 2490, 2590, 2570, 2550, 2620, 2620, 
    2550, 2520, 2510, 2490, 2470, 2380, 2430, 2460, 2530, 2470, 
    2390, 2450, 2510, 2450, 2490, 2360, 2370, 2470, 2360, 2400, 
    2370, 2360, 2420, 2490, 2440, 2420, 2460, 2440, 2560, 2530, 
    2530, 2660, 2750, 2710, 2700, 2790, 2810, 2460, 2720, 2730, 
    2520, 2610, 2320, 2220, 2270, 2140, 2220, 2130, 2300, 2220, 
    2320, 2340, 2310, 2450, 2490, 2450, 2530, 2650, 2630, 2640, 
    2720, 2790, 2870, 2880, 2870, 3050, 2890, 2820, 2870, 2980, 
    2990, 2910, 2990, 3060, 3060, 2980, 3090, 3070, 3100, 3130, 
    3120, 3390, 3220, 3210, 3220, 3400, 3240, 3330, 3260, 3480, 
    3320, 3240, 3270, 3410, 3130, 3160, 2990, 3180, 2920, 2800, 
    2660, 2750, 2630, 2470, 2480, 2410, 2250, 2380, 2370, 2380, 
    2400, 2380, 2430, 2420, 2490, 2420, 2520, 2490, 2660, 2610, 
    2670, 2730, 2880, 2840, 2790, 2870, 3040, 2950, 3050, 3060, 
    3410, 3160, 3270, 3280, 3430, 3350, 3380, 3370, 3590, 3370, 
    3480, 3620, 3640, 3530, 3620, 3670, 3570, 3610, 3610, 3650, 
    3630, 3680, 3730, 3850, 3750, 3770, 3870, 4050, 3940, 3990, 
    4090, 4170, 4100, 4180, 4250, 4160, 4230, 4090, 4120, 3870, 
    3830, 3810, 3880, 3710, 3730, 3910, 3700, 3690, 3700, 3810, 
    3740, 3570, 3410, 3440, 3190, 3090, 3080, 3190, 3040, 2980, 
    2950, 2870, 2950, 2850, 2600, 2570, 2450, 2360, 2340, 2160, 
    2360, 2150, 2240, 2320, 2120, 2280, 2090, 2280, 2260, 2310, 
    2480, 2490, 2550, 2740, 2820, 3040, 3040, 3060, 3100, 3200, 
    3180, 3140, 3370, 3170, 3230, 3180, 3360, 3190, 3210, 3190, 
    3340, 3100, 3030, 2900, 2980, 2770, 2630, 2660, 2570, 2580, 
    2480, 2400, 2370, 2530, 2390, 2390, 2450, 2510, 2540, 2500, 
    2470, 2490, 2640, 2530, 2570, 2540, 2680, 2650, 2690, 2570, 
    2620, 2770, 2690, 2680, 2740, 2870, 2790, 2760, 2800, 3030, 
    2890, 2940, 3010, 3180, 3100, 3130, 3140, 3330, 3150, 3280, 
    3250, 3560, 3400, 3430, 3480, 3680, 3490, 3540, 3580, 3650, 
    3470, 3500, 3520, 3710, 3570, 3670, 3720, 3870, 3760, 3770, 
    3840, 4010, 3760, 3740, 3850, 3680, 3600, 3510, 3650, 3780, 
    3420, 3460, 3480, 3300, 3500, 3230, 3290, 3270, 3460, 3380, 
    3430, 3400, 3190, 3000, 3060, 2940, 2920, 3130, 2780, 2840, 
    2750, 2740, 3010, 2820, 2710, 2650, 2590, 2820, 2690, 2530, 
    2500, 2450, 2590, 2480, 2440, 2420, 2610, 2440, 2390, 2530, 
    2470, 2370, 2430, 2410, 2290, 2430, 2330, 2330, 2340, 2230, 
    2180, 2190, 2100, 2010, 2160, 1940, 1960, 1960, 2040, 1960, 
    1900, 1940, 1950, 1990, 2010, 2130, 2000, 2090, 2010, 2040, 
    2060, 2080, 2160, 2180, 2230, 2240, 2280, 2290, 2280, 2330, 
    2400, 2340, 2380, 2390, 2400, 2340, 2340, 2360, 2400)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-744L))
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Sharing data using `dput` is **important** to understand the exact issue in your data. My answer still works when I use your new data. Check with `data <- structure(list(xxx_877963267 = c(24.456, 12.5667, 67.3453, 0.3456, 
4.5675), xxx_9073498356 = c(5.8799, 2.5643, 7.4573, 1.7398, 2.3345
), xxx_07839328 = c(4.7854, 0.7867, 6.3298, 2.3585, 2.3556)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))` . which is same as your shown dataset. Does it work for you, using this data? What is `class(data$xxx_877963267)` ? It would be helpful if you share data using `dput`.

Comment: Somehow it works with your data. I'm totally confused.

Comment: Your `dput` is not complete. I cannot copy-paste it. Can you add `dput(head(data))` and make sure that it can be copy-pasted just like how I did in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah , it was pretty hard to also make sure the result was correct, but now i can proceed with my masters thesis.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Assuming your data is something like this :

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(20, 34, 50, 12, 10), b = c(55, 76, 21, 10, 11), c = 1:5)
data
#   a  b c
#1 20 55 1
#2 34 76 2
#3 50 21 3
#4 12 10 4
#5 10 11 5
```

You can keep the columns that do not have any value over 50 by

1. Using `colSums` :

```
data[, colSums(data > 50) == 0]

#   a c
#1 20 1
#2 34 2
#3 50 3
#4 12 4
#5 10 5
```

2. Using `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) all(x <= 50), data)
```

3. In `dplyr` using `select`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% select(where(~all(. <= 50)))
```

If your data has `NA`'s you can set `na.rm = TRUE` argument in the functions above.

Comment: Okay, now i found problem. The problem is that my column names have letters and numbers, so that why it isn't working. Or can it be so? It gives me really weird answers that have some columns randomly. How can i go around it? because i need column names to stay intact with the dataframe.

Comment: @JoelLänsisalmi I don't think column names are an issue here. We don't do anything to column names here. Same answer works for this data with letters and numbers as column names. `data <- data.frame(a1 = c(20, 34, 50, 12, 10), b2 = c(55, 76, 21, 10, 11), c3 = 1:5)`. Add `dput(head(data))` to your post.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` in `base R`

```
data[sapply(data, sum) > 50]
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(20, 34, 50, 12, 10), b = c(55, 76, 21, 10, 11), c = 1:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind packages:

```r
library(data.table)
library(hutils)
library(hutilscpp)

library(nycflights13)  # for sample data


flights_dt <- as.data.table(flights)  # for select_which
select_which(flights_dt, function(x) is.numeric(x) && !which_first(x > 50))
#>         month day hour
#>      1:     1   1    5
#>      2:     1   1    5
#>      3:     1   1    5
#>      4:     1   1    5
#>      5:     1   1    6
#>     ---               
#> 336772:     9  30   14
#> 336773:     9  30   22
#> 336774:     9  30   12
#> 336775:     9  30   11
#> 336776:     9  30    8

# flights <- as.data.frame(flights) or  <- as_tibble(flights)  as desired
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>